# How do I feed a Keras network a sample matrix to debug?

Tags: lambda, keras, layer

I'm working my way through [this tutorial](https://keunwoochoi.wordpress.com/2016/11/18/for-beginners-writing-a-custom-keras-layer/) and I wanted to understand exactly how a layer operation works. So I extended the first example like what is shown below. I'm not exactly sure what I will get out of this network, so I want to feed in a tensor with the right dimensions and see what the output is. How do I do that?

Using: keras 2.0.2

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation
from keras.layers import Lambda

model = Sequential([
    Dense(32, input_shape=(10, 12, 14)),
    Activation('relu'),
    Dense(16),
    Activation('softmax'),
])
def output_of_lambda(input_shape):
    return (input_shape[0], 1, input_shape[2])

def mean(x):
    return K.mean(x, axis=1, keepdims=True)

model.add(Lambda(mean, output_shape=output_of_lambda))

model.summary()
```

Output:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_9 (Dense)              (None, 10, 12, 32)        480       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_9 (Activation)    (None, 10, 12, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_10 (Dense)             (None, 10, 12, 16)        528       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_10 (Activation)   (None, 10, 12, 16)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
lambda_6 (Lambda)            (None, 1, 12)             0         
=================================================================
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just do a `predictions = model.predict(data)`.

Where data is your input data, which must be in the shape of `(any,10,12,14)`.

For passing a single sample instead of a batch, the shape must be `(1,10,12,14)`.

Answer (score 1):

Daniel is right, also one can create a keras function using the backend

Here is an example:

```
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation
from keras.layers import Lambda


model = Sequential([
    Dense(32, input_shape=(10, 12, 14)),
    Activation('relu'),
    Dense(16),
    Activation('softmax'),
])
def output_of_lambda(input_shape):
    return (input_shape[0], 1, input_shape[2])

def mean(x):
    return K.mean(x, axis=1, keepdims=True)

model.add(Lambda(mean, output_shape=output_of_lambda))
model.summary()

# add a function to push some data through the model
func = K.function([model.inputs[0], K.learning_phase()], [model.outputs[0]]

X = np.random.randn(100, 10, 12, 14)
print(func([X, 0]))
```

That gives you the flexibility to see what *any* layer outputs, just 
by changing the K.function ... `[model.outputs[0]] to [model.layers[2].output]` which gives you the output of the second dense layer

See the keras faq about the matter: [how-can-i-obtain-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer)

Comment: Thank you for that hint!